# How can I increase the size of a RAID 1 array from 750GB to 1TB? 3ware

Tags: raid1, 3ware

3ware 9650SE-2LP

Array is 750GB volume, RAID 1. One drive is 750GB, the other is 1TB. Looking to replace the 750GB drive with a 1TB. Will the array rebuild to the max size of 1TB, or will the array need to be broken and remade from the first drive? I need to retain the data so that once it's all done I can resize the /home ext3 partition to take up the added space.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You de-split it into separate disks, then convert into degraded RAID1 and then add the second disk. That's how we migrated. Stupid, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I **think** you might be able to use resize2fs to do this ... from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs) it states:

> The resize2fs program does not manipulate the size of partitions. If you wish to enlarge a filesystem, you must first make sure you can expand the size of the underlying partition first. This can be done using fdisk(8) by deleting the partition and recreating it with a larger size or using lvextend(8), if you're using the logical volume manager lvm(8). **When recreating the partition, make sure you create it with the same starting disk cylinder as before! Otherwise, the resize operation will certainly not work, and you may lose your entire filesystem.** After running fdisk(8), run resize2fs to resize the ext2 filesystem to use all of the space in the newly enlarged partition.

YMMV, no warranty implied, backup your data to be on the safe side!

Comment: Doesn't work, you first need to increase the unit before you can resize the fs

Answer (score 1):

Bad news.

According to the [User docs](http://www.3ware.com/support/UserDocs/CLIGuide-9.5.2.pdf), RAID1 to RAID1 is not a valid migration path (check the manual under the '/cx/ux migrate' section).

Since the manual says it's not possible, and you're going to be moving your data off anyway...why not try it and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

RAID 1 will take the smallest drive size as it's maximum.

Replacing your 750GB with a 1 TB will increase the array size to 1 TB and keep everything in tact.