# Increasing the size of a 3ware 9650SE RAID5

Tags: raid, lsi, 3ware

These questions seemed similar, but they did not worK:

- [Why is the 9650SE RAID1 not showing the full size of the disks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/476720/why-is-the-9650se-raid1-not-showing-the-full-size-of-the-disks)
- [How can I increase the size of a RAID 1 array from 750GB to 1TB? 3ware](https://serverfault.com/questions/191034/how-can-i-increase-the-size-of-a-raid-1-array-from-750gb-to-1tb-3ware)

Here is my RAID configuration from tw_cli /c0 show all

```
/c1 Driver Version = 2.26.02.014
/c0 Model = 9650SE-4LPML
/c0 Available Memory = 224MB
/c0 Firmware Version = FE9X 4.10.00.024
/c0 Bios Version = BE9X 4.08.00.004
/c0 Boot Loader Version = BL9X 3.08.00.001
/c0 Serial Number = L326009A9151022
/c0 PCB Version = Rev 035
/c0 PCHIP Version = 2.00
/c0 ACHIP Version = 1.90
/c0 Number of Ports = 4
/c0 Number of Drives = 4
/c0 Number of Units = 1
/c0 Total Optimal Units = 1
/c0 Not Optimal Units = 0
/c0 JBOD Export Policy = off
/c0 Disk Spinup Policy = 1
/c0 Spinup Stagger Time Policy (sec) = 1
/c0 Auto-Carving Policy = off
/c0 Auto-Carving Size = 2048 GB
/c0 Auto-Rebuild Policy = on
/c0 Rebuild Mode = Adaptive
/c0 Rebuild Rate = 1
/c0 Verify Mode = Adaptive
/c0 Verify Rate = 1
/c0 Controller Bus Type = PCIe
/c0 Controller Bus Width = 4 lanes
/c0 Controller Bus Speed = 2.5 Gbps/lane

Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-5    OK             -       -       256K    8381.87   RiW    ON

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   5.45 TB   SATA  0   -            WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1
p1    OK             u0   5.45 TB   SATA  1   -            WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1
p2    OK             u0   5.45 TB   SATA  2   -            WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1
p3    OK             u0   5.45 TB   SATA  3   -            WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1
```

Neither with tw_cli nor with 3dm2 can I make use of the larger disks.  I tried:

```
# tw_cli /c0/u0 migrate type=raid5 disk=0-3 
Error: (CLI:008) Invalid ID specified.  Found a specified ID already in use.
```

With 3dm2, I selected the unit, clicked on "Migrate unit" and it said: 
NO DRIVES AVAILABLE TO USE FOR MIGRATE

What am I missing?

Comment: IIRC the new drive becomes a hot spare automatically, which would mark it as "in use". Not an answer because I can't verify.

Comment: Also, at that size, RAID-5 is a ticking time bomb IMO. With a 4-port controller, you don't have too many other options, but your ability to rebuild after a failure depends on none of the disks having even a single error.

Comment: you can't migrate to the same set of drives you're migrating from.  I'd buy a NAS box (QNAP, Synology) copy all your stuff over, format your raid to the new bigger size.  Keep the box and you can have a good backup in case your raid takes a dump someday.

Comment: user16081-JoeT basically has it, and it is similar to what I ended up doing.